# Developing Meteor.js app on both Win and Mac systems

Tags: node.js, meteor

If I create a Meteor.js app on the Mac and starts developing and adding Atmosphere packages with `meteorite`, can I continue developing on a Windows system (code synced using git) where `meteorite` is not installed and doesn't run on Windows? Whenever I need to change the meteor smart packages I will use the Mac system.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible because the symlinks wont easily copy over. The way I get passed this is I "hard" install the atmosphere packages into `/packages`.

You would notice on a mac that there are symlinks in the `/packages` directory of your application. If you follow them & then copy over all the contents into a new directory that replaces the original symlinks with the same names your package should work on both windows & mac with git sync.

When a new version comes out though, you need to update the files again or before you deploy your app you could substitute the packages back to symlinks by just deleting them all and running `mrt update` to fetch the packages back.